# An error occured during processing in authorize.net sandbox account

Tags: php, authorize.net, zen-cart

I am using zencart and using authorize.net for one of my payment module, So customers can pay directly through credit card. I have a authorize.net sandbox account. Last night I test it and everything was fine. But now when we test in sandbox mode, an error occurred and it says -

"An error occurred during processing. Please try again. - Your credit card could not be authorized for this reason."

I search in google and know that the error code is E00001 .

I just want to know why this is happen? what is the type of error and which file is responsible? and why this error comes up in testing mode? Please help me

Comment: Double check whether you're in sandbox

Comment: Yes I checked several times and it is sandbox account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An administrator of developer.authorize.net explains the same error code a couple of years ago here: http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/CIM-test-code-giving-error-E00001-An-error-occurred-during/td-p/3733/page/2

Comment: Thanks Blue, the problem is solved, may be there database is down or whatever, I just login to the sandbox portal and turn on the test mode from Account section and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

authorize.net might be down at the moment

Answer (score 0):

i use the authorize.net CIM module.

i have encountered the E00001 error when executing a:

createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest

and the

customerPaymentProfileId

was wrong.  in my case, customerPaymentProfileId had been deleted and was therefore no longer valid for that customer.